# Does a transparent hair-covering fulfil the halacha?

Tags: halacha, see-sight-vision-blind, hair-covering

We learn the mitzvah of a married woman covering her hair from the verse in Bamidbar (5:18) וּפָרַע אֶת רֹאשׁ הָאִשָּׁה. The Talmud in various places expounds on the details.

While I am very aware that wearing a transparent hair covering is not in the "spirit" of the law, would it be technically considered permissible? The Torah says the hair of the Sotah was "uncovered", implying the mitzvah is to "cover".

Comment: Just to add- my initial thoughts are that it is not permissible, as the purpose of uncovering would be null and void if the covering was transparent. In other words, the whole purpose of covering is so that another cannot see! Thoughts anyone?

Comment: I don't know how you know what the whole purpose of the covering (deorayta) is, nor how you know it isn't in the spirit of the law.

Comment: I did not mean to suggest I know the whole purpose of covering, I was merely suggesting that generally one covers parts of the body so that it is not visible, such as in the case of Adam and Chava when Hashem created garments for them. Would you disagree with that? Also, I was suggesting that it was not in the spirit of the law using svara or common sense based on the points I have just made. @DoubleAA

Comment: A similar question can be asked concerning sheitels. Some are so real looking (genuine human hair) it would, figuratively speaking, be as if they were transparent.  I understand certain frumsters don't approve of such head coverings but most seem to prefer them.

Comment: @JJLL What is a frumster? Sounds pejorative...

Comment: Not at all Gadol.  Frumster is actually an indearing term referring  to observant Jews.  Frumster.com was a dating site for Orthodox Jews. See the following Yeshiva World News article:  http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/frumster-versus-saw-you-at-sinai.    Shabbat Shalom.

Comment: @jjll ,one can technically use their own detached hair as a covering,see the Shiltei Giborim ,and Mishna Brurah Hilchos Krias shema

Comment: You mean like covering her hair with a wicker basket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can ask if a person can be undressed and stand in front of their front window, but that obviously is a breach of *tznius*. Why should this be any different?

In the laws of Shma(75:5) it says that *Ervah ba'Ashashis* (unclothedness in glass) is also *untznius* and someone else can't say Shma facing them so your case where she is wearing a transparent hair covering it's the same, as *Mishne Brurah* (25) writes.

See *Halichos Bas Yisroel* (4:6) where he writes

> Areas of the body covered by transparent clothing are considered
>   exposed.

Comment: What about the obligation to cover hair, though? This just addresses if it is modest, which is a separate concern, and one which is very possibly a time- and location-specific one. A hair covering with pornography on it is also immodest, but might fulfill the obligation to cover hair.

Comment: Pornography on the hair covering is a covering of the hair, but introduces a *new* immodesty issue. Invisible hair covering does not solve the original issue of ervah at all. If it is still ervah for Shma it is obviously not resolving the Das Moshe/Yehudis requirement of covering ervah

Comment: The point of Das Moshe is to help men say keriat shema??? You have it backwards. Men only can't say keriat shema because it is a covered place, because of Das Moshe. You're putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: @DoubleAA Not sure what you're  reading...Ervah is ervah. Ervah for shma is ervah. Ervah for kisui is ervah. If you have a proof that the guidelines for ervah are different, fine.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What exactly do you want me to clarify? Das Moshe says they must somewhat cover their hair in the shuk. Doesn't say anything about Kerias Shema. The rule for Kerias Shema is you can't read it in front of a tefach of an area which is usually covered. So if hair is usually covered (which it is, at least due to Das Yehudis) then you can't read Kerias Shema in front of it. What does that have to do with Das Moshe?

Comment: 1. The obligation to cover hair stems from the hair being ervah. 2. Hair covered with tranparent covering is ervah as seen in hilchos Shma. Thus, transparent covering is still ervah and not considered covering. Not sure where you're having a difficulty.

Comment: As I said before: you just made up number 1.

Comment: @DoubleAA Ah...so you think covering hair is a gezeiras hakasuv and not dependent on ervah and tznius?

Comment: Ervah and tzniyus depend __on it__. Something normally covered should stay covered. That's ervah and tzniyus. That doesn't explain why it started being normally covered. In this case, the answer is God said so. We see by Betulos who are regilos not to cover hair that it isn't erva. Erva is fundamentally based on regilus.

Comment: IMHO social norms (like betulot regilos) are one element that may determine erva (exceptions like knee and above is erva intrinsically). Erva determines requirement to cover. IMHO You have it backward

Comment: Not everyone agrees knee and above is ervah intrinsically. And not everyone agrees knee and below is not ervah intrinsically. Either way, the ervah which is potentially above the knee is probably rabbinic. Das Moshe is deoraysa. Mideoraysa you only can't say kerias shema in front of genitals (even your own).

Comment: @Yoni I haven't looked that up inside but I suspect he is being loose with his words. Anyway you still haven't shown that exposed means uncovered. (Incidentally, I believe R Mordechai Willig of RIETS holds that all appendage coverings (arm/leg) is entirely Minhag dependent. Presumably that would indicate he doesn't think it's Das Moshe. I don't know why you think the fact that non-Jews behaved a certain way till the 60s is relevant. Sources are very important in Judaism, even for [things otherwise thought obvious](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1101.htm#1). Why would it be Das Moshe anyway?)

Comment: @BabySeal The gemara's use of those verses in Isaiah is in all likelihood a reference to the calf.

Comment: @doubleaa please do look it up being he is actually addressing your precise point viz whether thigh is dad Moshe or das Yehudis. An actual source that rabbi Willig maintains as you claim he does will be enlightening. Thanks!

Comment: @Yoni I was referring to the quote you added to the answer as being imprecise. I'm pretty sure RMW says it in [this shiur](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/754862/Rabbi_Mordechai_I_Willig/Women_in_Halacha_#5_-_Modest_Dress)

Comment: @Yoni I don't see what you are referring to in HBY about thigh being Dat Moshe. I'm using the Hebrew version; does that explain why I don't see anything in 4:8, as you claimed?

Comment: @doubleaa I was citing the English edition. Hebrew edition has much improved sources and shouldn't be hard to find

Comment: @Yoni Looked through it over Shabbat but still seem to be missing it. Do you have access to the Hebrew to point it out to me? Could it be only in the English?

Comment: @DoubleAA Source is English..I have not looked in Hebrew version for this, but usually Hebrew versions are more complete.

Comment: @Yoni Just got myself an English copy, and boy is it different. I'd stick to the Hebrew if you are able to. The English adds in more text and footnotes, but not correlated to each other. So you have text that is unsourced, and footnotes which are sometimes iffy. Consider the line "Talmudic commentators deduce..." on page 76. I know of no talmudic commentator who made such a claim and neither did the Beit Yosef 75. I even know of commentators who have said otherwise. His terminology in the extended footnotes is also loose. The "Law of Shoke" and "Law of Tefach" are terms which AFICT he made up

Answer (score 4):

You are indeed correct. A transparent covering does fulfill the Torah obligation you reference for a married woman to cover her hair. (Note though that there are other rabbinic issues at play besides the biblical requirement you mention, so leaving any hair visible may still not be acceptable in the final halachic analysis.)

Rabbi Mordechai Willig makes this claim explicitly in minute 29 of [this recording](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/754864/Rabbi_Mordechai_I_Willig/Women_in_Halacha_#7:_Hair_Covering_(Cont'd)_&_Kol_Isha). Indeed it is hard to imagine anyone disagreeing with this claim as the Talmud (Ketubot 72) is clear that a *kalta* (some sort of basket) fulfills said obligation, and according to many, many Rishonim (see lists and analysis in Benei Vanim 3:21 and 3:25:5) a *kalta* did not cover all the hair (either because it had holes or because it wasn't big enough). In other words, the Talmud is clear that a covering does not have to effect the removal of visible "*ervah*" in order to qualify for said obligation.

Comment: The other answer appears to be unfortunately confused about a number of concepts, as it is discussing regulations about concealing _ervah_. (Always worth looking back at original sources instead of making _diyukim_ in late 20th century English Halacha guides.)